# Why doesn't rev(factor) work as a way to reverse the wt argument of dplyr::top_n()?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, top-n

Goal: return the row with thing1=F and thing2=MeFirst

Why does this not work?

```
tibble(
    row = 1:10,
    thing1 = c(rep("F",5),rep("L",5)),
    thing2 = c(rep("MeSecond",4),rep("MeFirst",2),rep("MeSecond",4))
) %>%
    mutate(
        thing1 = factor(thing1, levels = c("F", "L")),
        thing2 = factor(thing2, levels = c("MeFirst", "MeSecond"))
    ) %>%
    top_n(
        .,
        n = 1,
        wt = rev(thing1)
    ) %>%
    top_n(
        .,
        n = 1,
        wt = rev(thing2)
    )
```

Above returns rows 2:5.

I know this *does* work:

```
tibble(
    row = 1:10,
    thing1 = c(rep("F",5),rep("L",5)),
    thing2 = c(rep("MeSecond",4),rep("MeFirst",2),rep("MeSecond",4))
) %>%
    mutate(
        thing1 = factor(thing1, levels = c("F", "L")),
        thing2 = factor(thing2, levels = c("MeFirst", "MeSecond"))
    ) %>%
    top_n(
        .,
        n = -1,
        wt = thing1
    ) %>%
    top_n(
        .,
        n = -1,
        wt = thing2
    )
```

But the question is, why doesn't rev(thing2) work?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that you want to reverse the levels of the factor but not the factor itself:

```
library(dplyr)
library(forcats)

tibble(row = 1:10,
       thing1 = c(rep("F", 5), rep("L", 5)),
       thing2 = c(rep("MeSecond", 4), rep("MeFirst", 2), rep("MeSecond", 4))) %>%
  mutate(thing1 = factor(thing1, levels = c("F", "L")),
         thing2 = factor(thing2, levels = c("MeFirst", "MeSecond"))) %>%
  top_n(n = 1, wt = fct_rev(thing1)) %>%
  top_n(n = 1, wt = fct_rev(thing2))

# A tibble: 1 x 3
    row thing1 thing2 
  <int> <fct>  <fct>  
1     5 F      MeFirst
```